# My line schedule does not work although I get data from GoogleSheets developer console

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet, chart.js2

I'm trying to create a project that takes data from GoogleSheet and outputs it to the website as a linear graph, but somehow it doesn't work on the website, even though the graph itself is, and the data is in console.log, but I can't understand why the lines on the diagram don't work.[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ChartComponent from './chart';
import fetchDataFromSheets from './spreadsheet'
import './Style.css'

const App = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const credentials = require('./service-account.json');
    const sheetId = 'ID GoogleSheet';

    fetchDataFromSheets(sheetId, credentials)
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        setChartData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='chart-container'>
        <ChartComponent data={chartData} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import { Chart as ChartJS} from 'chart.js/auto';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';


const ChartComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const chartData = {
    labels: data.map(d => d.Date),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'PriceBefore',
        data: data.map(d => d.PriceBefore),
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      },
      {
        label: 'PriceAfter',
        data: data.map(d => d.PriceAfter),
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      }
    ]
  };

  return <Line data={chartData} />;
};

export default ChartComponent

import '../interface/Style.css'
import App from './logic'


export default function Interface() {
  return (
    <div className='container'>

      <header className='header'>
        
      </header>

      
      <div className='graph'></div>

      <footer className='footer'>
        <App />
        
      </footer>
   </div>
  );
}

import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet';
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library';

async function fetchDataFromSheets(sheetId) {
  const serviceAccountAuth = new JWT({
    email: "PrivateEmail",
    key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEYEND PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
  });

  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId, serviceAccountAuth);

  await doc.loadInfo();
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; // 

  const rows = await sheet.getRows();
  console.log(rows)

  return rows.map(row => ({
    date: row['Date'],
    price: row['Price']
  }));
}

export default fetchDataFromSheets;
```

And my JSON file

```
{
  "name": "my-stone-market",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.1",
    "google-auth-library": "^9.4.1",
    "google-spreadsheet": "^4.1.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-social-icons": "^6.7.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are saying that the data is retrieved OK and shows in the console as expected, which indicates that the issue is not with the spreadsheet nor Sheets API. Perhaps you should remove spreadsheet and Sheets API tags and add a React tag?

Comment: I'm not well-versed in React but I believe the issue's with the return values of the function `fetchDataFromSheets()`. It returns an array of objects with the properties `date` and `price`. `ChartComponent`, however, expects three properties; `date`, `PriceBefore`, and `PriceAfter`. The latter two do not exist on the object returned by `fetchDataFromSheets().`